# What are differences among spring-cloud-dependencies, spring-cloud-context and spring-cloud-commons?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I want to build a spring cloud project, but I find these three dependencies confusing, if we want to build a spring-cloud project, which of these three dependencies should be used? do they contain each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-commons:

- **Spring Cloud Context** provides utilities and special services for the ApplicationContext of a Spring Cloud application (bootstrap context, encryption, refresh scope and environment endpoints)
- **Spring Cloud Commons** is a set of abstractions and common classes used in different Spring Cloud implementations (eg. Spring Cloud Netflix vs. Spring Cloud Consul).

Comment: so both of them should be used? also how about  spring-cloud-dependencies?

Comment: Frankly, never heard of `spring-cloud-dependencies`. Moreover, you don't need to use any of them directly since they are usually part of aggregated dependency packages under the hood of Spring Boot Cloud starters. The best way I found to learn Spring Cloud is to try to implement features on microservices like load-balancing, authorization etc.  and microservices themselves - this way you explore the best the inner components of Spring Cloud and the way they work together.

Comment: what I mean is what should I put in pom.xml